# PlaywrightCrawler continuous loading does not trigger handlePageFunction

Tags: playwright, apify

I have a PlaywrightCrawler to scrape Alibaba. But when I add a request to one page like:

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Mono-filament-12-mm-PP-fiber_1600139352513.html?spm=a27aq.industry_category_productlist.dt_3.1.3d733642TkHgZc

This page lasted to loading until timeout and handlePageFunction didn't be called.

Actually, all the content has been loaded completed. I notice that some AJAX runs in the background.

How do I force PlaywrightCrawler to call handlePageFunction even though AJAX didn't complete it?

```
const crawler = new Apify.PlaywrightCrawler({
    requestQueue,


    launchContext: {
        launchOptions: {
            headless: false,
        },
    },
    handlePageFunction,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your waitUntil parameter to go to the page as soon as the DOM loads using this:

```js
const crawler = new Apify.PlaywrightCrawler({
    requestQueue,
    // ...
    preNavigationHooks: [async (context, gotoOptions) => {
       gotoOptions.waitUntil = 'domcontentloaded';
    }],
});
```

this will fire as soon as the page is ready to be queried by `document.querySelectorAll`, you may have to wait for certain conditions inside the `handlePageFunction` before starting to call `page` methods